# Why are my class's variables not unique for each object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Why is it that the object `b` has the same variables as `a` and not unique ones?

```py
class FOO: 
 
    def __init__(self):
         FOO.x = [3, 1]
         self.y = [9, 4] 
 
    def g(self):
         FOO.x[1] = FOO.x[1] + 7
         self.y *= 2
         return FOO.x + self.y 
 
a, b = FOO(), FOO() 
print(a.g()) 
print(a.g()) 
print(b.g())
```

Why do I get this output:

> [3, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4]
>
> [3, 15, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4]
>
> [3, 22, 9, 4, 9, 4]

and not this?

> [3, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4]
>
> [3, 15, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4]
>
> [3, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4]

Isn't each object unique?

Comment: Why are you using `FOO.x` instead of `self.x`?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `Foo.x` and `self.x`? Why did you use `Foo.x` and `self.y`?

Comment: Because you are changing class attributes `Foo.x` which changes it for all instances , instead use `self.x` which is an instance attribute

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that.
btw, that's a question that I was trying to solve but didn't notice the Foo.x instead of self

still why does b inherit from a

Comment: @JoelBerkeley , my question is why does b inherit from a

Comment: Yes, which boils down to the difference between class and instance variables (btw `b` doesn't _inherit_ from `a` - _inherit_ means sth else)

Comment: @JoelBerkeley, I feel stupid how I didn't notice that, thanks anyway.

I didn't notice that the variable is a class variable.

I thought that b inherited something from a since I didn't notice the Foo.x

Comment: @JoelBerkeley, sorry if I used wrong terms since I don't study in english

Comment: ah no bother. we all miss things. and I picked up on _inherit_ because it means sth very specific in programming and you or someone else will get confused if you try to use it to mean something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FOO.x` variable belongs to the FOO class, not to each instance. So, when you're adding `7` to `FOO[1]`, you're changing the value for all object instances.